# proper way to split / rejoin a Flux

Tags: project-reactor

is the following the proper/idiomatic way to split off a Flux into different processing paths and join them back - for the purpose of the question, events shouldn't be discarded, ordering is unimportant, and memory is unlimited.

```java
Flux<Integer> beforeFork = Flux.range(1, 10);

ConnectableFlux<Integer> forkPoint = beforeFork
    .publish()
;

Flux<String> slowPath = forkPoint
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .map(i -> "slow"+"_"+i)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
;

Flux<String> fastPath = forkPoint
        .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
        .map(i -> "fast"+"_"+i)
;

// merge vs concat since we need to eagerly subscribe to
// the ConnectableFlux before the connect()
Flux.merge(fastPath, slowPath)
    .map(s -> s.toUpperCase()) // pretend this is a more complex sequence
    .subscribe(System.out:println)
;
forkPoint.connect();
```

i suppose i could also groupBy() then filter() on key() if the filter() function was slower than %.

NOTE that i do want the slowPath and fastPath to consume the same events from the beforeFork point since beforeFork is slow to produce.

NOTE that i do have a more complex followup (i.e. change to `range(1,100)` and the behavior around the prefetch boundary is confusing to me) - but i'd only make sense if the above snippet is legal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is more common to see this written this way:

```java
Flux<Integer> beforeFork = Flux.range(1, 10).publish().autoConnect(2);

Flux<String> slowPath = beforeFork
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .map(i -> "slow"+"_"+i)
    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

Flux<String> fastPath = beforeFork
    .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
    .map(i -> "fast"+"_"+i);

Flux.merge(fastPath, slowPath)
    .map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .blockLast();
```

A summary of the changes:

- `autoConnect(N)` - allows us to specify that the `beforeFork` publisher is connected to after N subscribers. If we know the number of expected paths upfront, we can specify this and prevent caching or duplicate execution the publisher.
- `blockingLast()` - we block on the joining `Flux` itself. You might have noticed that if you ran your current code only the fast results appear to be logged. This is because we were not actually waiting for the slow results to complete.

This is assuming that your original `Publisher` is finite with a fixed number of elements. Other changes would need to be made for something like `Flux.interval` or an ongoing stream.

For `prefetch` I can refer you to this question:
[What does prefetch mean in Project Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675511/what-does-prefetch-mean-in-project-reactor)